# How to print a sublist that contains all of the strings in another list?

Tags: python

```
search_terms = ['word','word 1','word 2']

library = [['desk','chair','lamp'],['cow','word','horse','word 2','word 1']]
```

I just want to be able to print all list(s) in library that contain ALL of the terms in search_terms. the list search_terms will not always have the same number of strings...

Thanks for anyone who is willing to help me!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`set.issubset`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes#set.issubset):

```
>>> {'word','word 1','word 2'}.issubset(['desk','chair','lamp'])
False
>>> {'word','word 1','word 2'}.issubset(['cow','word','horse','word 2','word 1'])
True
```

---

```
>>> search_terms = ['word','word 1','word 2']
>>> library = [['desk','chair','lamp'],['cow','word','horse','word 2','word 1']]
>>> terms = set(search_terms)
>>> [x for x in library if terms.issubset(x)]
[['cow', 'word', 'horse', 'word 2', 'word 1']]
```

Comment: thank you!!!!!!! what if one of the search_terms is in a library list, but is not the full string in library? like - the term in search_terms is 'word' but the term im searching in library is 'word 2345634'. can i search for if the library term just CONTAINS the terms search_terms? or should I start a new question for this?

Comment: @user3150759, Open a new question with examples.

Comment: ok. here it is if you want to take a crack at it: http://stackoverflow.com/q/20869575/3150759