# print a sublist that contains all strings in another list, without necessarily being a direct match

Tags: python

```
search_terms = ['word','cow','horse']

library = [['desk','chair','lamp'],['cow','horse','word 223','barn']]
```

I want to be able to print all list(s) in library that contain ALL of the terms in search_terms.

so using the above list of search_terms would print the second sublist in library even though 'word 223' just contains 'word', but is not a direct match.

I will not always have the same number of strings...

Thanks for anyone who is willing to help me!

and thanks to falsetru for helping me with my first question!

Comment: Try to show some code in future - people are generally unwilling to write answers for you. :)

Comment: @henrebotha I have no possible solution to this problem in mind, as i just started python 2 days ago. I don't have any relevant code to show beyond the lists i provided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get your hits, use a list comprehension:

```
search_terms = ['word', 'cow', 'horse']

library = [['desk', 'chair', 'lamp'],
           ['cow', 'horse', 'word 223', 'barn']]

hits = [l for l in library if 
        all(any(t in s for s in l) 
            for t in search_terms)]
```

This works as follows

1. `for` each sub-list `l` in your `library`;
2. `for` `all` terms `t` in `search_terms`;
3. `if` `any` of the strings `s` in `l` contains it;
4. Keep `l` in the new list `hits`.

Comment: I'm not generally a fan of this sort of complicated list comprehension, but it's a good answer.

Comment: it doesn't seem to be returning any results. it just returns an empty list.

Comment: @alvas no it isn't, my comp matches lists in library with extra items and where the term is only part of the item, per the OPs requirements

Comment: @jonrsharpe that's it! I still don't quite understand how it works lol, but I'll keep looking at it and I'll read about list comprehension. thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> search_terms = ['word','cow','horse']
>>> library = [['desk','chair','lamp'],['cow','horse','word 223','barn']]
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> list(chain(*library))
['desk', 'chair', 'lamp', 'cow', 'horse', 'word 223', 'barn']
>>> [word for word in search_terms if word in list(chain(*library))]
['cow', 'horse']
>>> [l for l in library if any(word for word in search_terms if word in l)]
[['cow', 'horse', 'word 223', 'barn']]
```

Comment: He wants to print each sublist, not a list of found search terms. The output should be `['cow','horse','word 223','barn']`.

Comment: oh... confusing question =)

Comment: @alvas sorry about that. feel free to edit to make clearer now that you know my intent. thanks for helping me.